How can I decode the encoded MediaCodec bytes using Node.js or JavaScript?
I am a new Java learner who created a screen recording application in Java. The application was working fine, but I converted the stream to bytes using mediacodec and sent it via socket connection through Node.js.
tried code:-
/MainActivity.java/
package com.example.viewer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAPTURE = 1001;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1002;

    private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection mediaProjection;
    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private Surface surface;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private socketClient socketClient;
    private EncoderThread encoderThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize socket client
        socketClient = new socketClient();

        // Request screen recording permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
            } else {
                startScreenRecording();
            }
        } else {
            // Lower API versions do not support screen recording
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Screen recording not supported on this device.");
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startScreenRecording();
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Permissions denied. Cannot start screen recording.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void startScreenRecording() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            if (mediaProjection != null) {
                // Configure MediaCodec
                try {
                    configureMediaCodec();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                // Start recording
                startRecording();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                1280, 720, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                surface, null, null);
        isRecording = true;

        // Start the encoder thread
        encoderThread = new EncoderThread();
        encoderThread.start();
    }

    private void configureMediaCodec() throws IOException {
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CAPTURE_RATE, 30);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 1000000 / 30);

        try {
            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");

            MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 2); // 2 seconds between I-frames

            mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            surface = mediaCodec.createInputSurface();
            mediaCodec.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error configuring MediaCodec: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Invalid argument for MediaCodec: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Illegal state exception for MediaCodec: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Unknown error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void stopScreenRecording() {
        if (isRecording) {
            isRecording = false;
            mediaProjection.stop();

            if (mediaCodec != null) {
                mediaCodec.stop();
                mediaCodec.release();
                mediaCodec = null;
            }

            Log.d("MainActivity", "Screen recording stopped.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopScreenRecording();
        socketClient.disconnect(); // Disconnect the socket when activity is destroyed
    }

    private class EncoderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            while (isRecording) {
                int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
                if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);
                    if (outputBuffer != null) {
                        byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                        outputBuffer.get(outData);
                        outputBuffer.clear();

                        // Send the encoded data over the socket
                        socketClient.sendData(outData);
                    }
                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I finally received the data at the node server socket, as shown below.
Buffer 00 00 00 01 41 9a aa c0 af 2f 57 fa bf cf 4e ba 03 ff 5e be af f5 ea 1a a6 c7 fa ff ea ff 5f fd 5f ea ff 57 ae af f5 7f ab fd 5f eb ff ab fd 7f f5 7f ... 2731 more bytes>
Can someone please confirm if the code above is correct? Also, could someone assist me with converting MediaCodec bytes using Node.js or JavaScript?
